# Importing a file to SQLite3 using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I know this question has been asked quite a few times but I cannot seem to get any of the ways described working.

I am trying to import a file to a database the file has columns of data seperated by a comma (i.e. csv). I have made a test file that resembles my actula file I would like to read in so here is the contents.

```
Wind_Speed, Wind_Direction, Wind_Max
10, 360, 12
13, 320, 11
12, 340, 14
12, 360, 14
```

Here is what I have been doing already.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.3

import csv, sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
cur = con.cursor()

with open('test.dat', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for column in reader:
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO jaws VALUES {}'.format(column))
con.commit()
```

And here is the error message,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csvdict.py", line 11, in <module>
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO jaws VALUES {}'.format(column))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "['Wind_Speed', ' Wind_Direction', ' Wind_Max']": syntax error
```

I am sure I am being stupid and missing something obvious but I can't see it.

Thanks

Comment: read the error message. it describes clearly where (and what) the problem is.

Comment: Your terminology is quite confusing. What you call "columns" are what everyone else calls "rows".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not formatting your data properly.

First of all your error message says you inserting what I assume to be your column names.

Secondly you should be careful [how you insert into sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613037/is-this-python-code-vulnerable-to-sql-injection-sqlite3).

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.3

import csv, sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
cur = con.cursor()

with open('test.dat', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    reader.next() # skip the headers
    for column in reader:
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO jaws VALUES (?,?,?)',tuple(i for i in column))
con.commit()
```

For a small file like your example one commiting changes at the end of the input is fine, but you might want to consider doing it more often for a larger file.  I have run into issues beacause of this in the past.

**EDIT:**

In response to the exception mentioned in your comment, here is an alternate way to skip the first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.3

import csv, sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
cur = con.cursor()

with open('test.dat', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    first = True
    for column in reader:
        if first:
            first = False
            continue
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO jaws VALUES (?,?,?)',tuple(i for i in column))
con.commit()
```

**EDIT2:**

In response to the exception mentioned in your comment, here is an alternate way to skip the first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.3

import csv, sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
cur = con.cursor()

with open('test.dat', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    skip_n = 4  # skips 4 lines
    skip_i = 0
    for column in reader:
        if skip_i < skip_n:
            skip_i += 1
            continue
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO jaws VALUES (?,?,?)',tuple(i for i in column))
con.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Farmer Joe, I have been trying iterations of this to no avail. I am getting a AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'next'.

Comment: @user3355986 Dropping that line will cause the headers to be inserted into your db...is that what you want?

Comment: @user3355986 See my edit for an alternative.  I am using python2.7 so that could be why my code threw an exception for you.

Comment: @user3355986 Also, no need for insults, their comment may have been unhelpful but name calling only perpetuates the negativity.  Share the love.

Comment: No that is not what I wanted, I will try this code out and see. I am not sure if I understand it correctly would I be able to skip more lines by adding second = True and so on?

Comment: @user3355986 If that solved your problem I would appreciate it if you could select it as the correct solution.