# What's the syntax for placeholders in the sqlite3 ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, sqlite

The following method returns an empty array

```
  def self.select_where(column, value)
    $db.execute(" SELECT *
                  FROM students
                  WHERE ? = ?", column, value)
  end
```

while the one below returns the proper row of the table.

```
  def self.select_where(column, value)
    $db.execute(" SELECT *
                  FROM students
                  WHERE #{column} = '#{value}'")
  end
```

What do I need to change to make the placeholders work? (sqlite3 gem)

Comment: You can't use parameters as the name of a column, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870284/can-i-use-parameters-for-the-table-name-in-sqlite3)

Comment: To add to @bhamby's point, the second example works since the string is being evaluated *before* it's passed to `$db.execute` as an entire query.