# Select with prepared statements Java

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc, prepared-statement

I just learned about prepared statements and now I'm trying to include them to my java program. However I get an exception when I try to add to values to the statement( table and name). When I prepare with only one variable it works fine.
What am I doing wrong?

> [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "?": syntax error)

```
String sql="SELECT * FROM ? WHERE name = ?";
    try {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, table);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, name);
        ResultSet checkTable = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: why not `String sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = ?";`?

Comment: because table is a variable, there can be 2 different tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how prepared statements work. Oddly enough, you [can't use placeholders for table names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5870340/783412). The solution being to use something like:

```
String sql = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE name = ?", table);
```

... and proceed with the rest of your code.

Comment: It is not odd that you can't, parameters are for passing values, a table name is not a value.

Answer (score 0):

Prepared statement are for values, a table name is not considered as being a value. So what you try to achieve is not possible.

That would work, though :

```
String sql="SELECT * FROM any_table_name WHERE name = ?";
try {
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
    ResultSet checkTable = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Comment: Thanks, what should i use if I need to pass table name as an argument than?

Answer (score 0):

Prepared statements are for column values not table names. You should do it as follows.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM `" + table + "` WHERE name = ?";
```