# Delphi FireDAC error working with parameters SQLite

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firedac

Good morning.

I'm with a problem that I can't figure out. The situation is the following:
I have a procedure that I call passing it a string, which is basically the name of a table.
In this particular case it is "sys".

This procedure basically executes the following lines:

```
Query.Close ();
Query.ParamByName ('TABLE'). AsString: = Table;
Query.Open;
```

"Query" basically has this:

```
SELECT * FROM: TABLE;
```

Therefore you should run the following:

```
SELECT * FROM sys;
```

Truth?

Well, apparently I'm having a bug. Since when testing it and executing my procedure this happens:

```
[FireDAC] [Phys] [SQLite] ERROR: near ": TABLE:" syntax error.
```

** Does SQLite work differently with parameters? **
I can not find why it fails.

Comment: Parameters can only be used for values not any identifiers or SQL keywords. This is true of all SQL dialects. Also the `:` needs to be at the start of a parameter name. So `SELECT * FROM PEOPLE WHERE FIRSTNAME = :FNAME` has a parameter called `FNAME`.

Comment: Firedac does have macros which can be used for everything. They are evaluated and the SQL updated before it is sent to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Base of SQLite document and  this link you can't pass table name as parameter:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870284/can-i-use-parameters-for-the-table-name-in-sqlite3][1]

Instead of that you can make your  string of query by this manner(trick):

```
Query.sql[1]:='tablename'
```

Default query string my be like this:

```
select * form
//X (line 1 )
where ....
```