# Python SQLite best way to use variables in query

Tags: python, sqlite

Why do i get this error?

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

when i run this:

```
c.execute('UPDATE ? SET Quantity = Quantity + ? WHERE Date = ?', (table, amount, date))
```

But not when i run this?

```
c.execute('UPDATE table1 SET Quantity = Quantity + ? WHERE Date = ?', (amount, date))
```

Variable value is:

```
table = 'table1'
amount = 20
Date = '12/5/2014'
```

I'm trying to dynamically create tables, but just doesn't work out.

Comment: What's the value of amount variable?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274432/sqlite-parameters-not-allowing-tablename-as-parameter. You cannot parameterize a table name.

Comment: Oh the quantity was the amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use placeholders for table names. You have to use normal Python string formatting or concatenation.

Comment: So something like this?

    
(`Table = 'table1'
c.execute('UPDATE '+Table+' SET Quantity = Quantity + ? WHERE        Date = ?', (amount, date))`)

Comment: Yes, or using the %s or {} string formatting operators.